# how to make the pin show bigger in Google map?

Tags: iphone, mapkit

any property can set the pin in google map bigger? from what i know, MKPinAnnotationView class only provided few properties but not any related to set custom pin size.

Pls help if have any idea.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @lee: Can you elaborate a little bit more on questions !!!

Comment: very simple i just want to make the Pin looks bigger on the map. the default pin in MKPinAnnotationView is too small for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `MKPinAnnotationView` is a subclass of `UIView` I believe you can explicitly set its frame.

As an alternative you can apply CGAffineTransform to your view to scale it appropriately.

```
pinView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the size of the frame in the pinView:

```
[pinView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 33, 33)];
```