# viewForAnnotation not being fired

Tags: ios, mapkit

I am displaying a pin on the map but I am not able to customize the display of the annotation view. For some reason my viewForAnnotation is not being called. Here is didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [mapView setDelegate:self]; 

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; 
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

    [mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];


    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;


}
```

And here is my viewForAnnotation method which is never being called.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mv:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

    NSLog(@"viewForAnnotation");

    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil; 

    static NSString *annotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier"; 
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];

    [pinView setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorGreen];
    pinView.animatesDrop = YES; 
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES; 

    UIImageView *houseIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"house.png"]];
    pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = houseIconView; 
    [houseIconView release]; 

    return pinView; 
}
```

and here is didUpdateUserLocation method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{

    NSTimeInterval t = [[[userLocation location] timestamp] timeIntervalSinceNow];

    if(t < -180) return; 

    NSLog(@"%@",[textField text]);

    MapPoint *mp = [[MapPoint alloc] initWithCoordinate:userLocation.location.coordinate title:[textField text]];



    [mv addAnnotation:mp];
    [mp release];

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `viewForAnnotation` delegate method must be named `mapView:viewForAnnotation:`.

Your method is named `mv:viewForAnnotation:`.

**Edit:**
Here is an example with the two other changes suggested in my comments:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    NSLog(@"viewForAnnotation");

    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil; 

    static NSString *annotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier"; 

    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [mapView 
        dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];

    if (!pinView) 
    {
        pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] 
            initWithAnnotation:annotation 
            reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier] autorelease];

        [pinView setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorGreen];
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES; 
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES; 

        UIImageView *houseIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"house.png"]];
        pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = houseIconView; 
        [houseIconView release];        
    }
    else 
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return pinView; 
}
```

Comment: you rock! Got it. Not sure why I changed the name from mapView to mv. hehe funny!

Comment: A couple of other things: you should use `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` and the bigger problem is a memory leak: add a `autorelease` on the pinView.

Comment: I used the following code but now I am getting back the default mkpinannotationview back:   MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: annotationIdentifier];

Comment: I'll add an example of what the method should look like.

Comment: Thanks! Also I wonder if there is anyway to change the size of the MKPinAnnotationView or AnnotationView in general. I want to display a large icon inside the AnnotationView.

Comment: Do you mean the size of the pin image or the leftCalloutAccessoryView?

Comment: pin image! I think we cannot change that. The only way I see is creating a custom annotation view. Thanks a million for the code!

Comment: To change the size of the pin image, you can try applying a CGAffineTransform like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442656/how-to-make-the-pin-show-bigger-in-google-map/2442692#2442692) but then the callout view size also changes.  Best option is to switch to a regular MKAnnotationView and return your own image but then you have to do your own drop animation.